# Is there a way to create tabs on category page in magento

Tags: php, jquery, css, magento, tabs

I was wondering If any one knows a simple way of creating tabs on category / home page in Magento which can then be filled to display various kinds of blocks (Most Viewed products/ New Products,etc )

There are various extensions which can display such products / blocks bt not in Tabs. Is there a way to modify the code so that it display it in Tabs.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check this link [Adding tab the homepage](http://www.lotusseedsdesign.com/blog/add-a-new-tab-at-homepage-for-a-category-product-listing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabs in Magento - this by default

you can try create  tab  on **view.phtml**

example -

**header**

```
<ul class="tabs" id="">
<li class="active first" id="product_tabs_description"><a href="javascript:void(0)">test1</a></li>
<li id="product_tabs_additional" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0)">test2</a></li>
</ul>
```

**content**

```
<div class="padder">
<div id="product_tabs_description_contents">test1</div>
<div id="product_tabs_additional_contents" style="display: none;">test2</div>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Varien.Tabs = Class.create();
Varien.Tabs.prototype = {
  initialize: function(selector) {
    var self=this;
    $$(selector+' a').each(this.initTab.bind(this));
  },

  initTab: function(el) {
      el.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
      if ($(el.parentNode).hasClassName('active')) {
        this.showContent(el);
      }
      el.observe('click', this.showContent.bind(this, el));
  },

  showContent: function(a) {
    var li = $(a.parentNode), ul = $(li.parentNode);
    ul.getElementsBySelector('li', 'ol').each(function(el){
      var contents = $(el.id+'_contents');
      if (el==li) {
        el.addClassName('active');
        contents.show();
      } else {
        el.removeClassName('active');
        contents.hide();
      }
    });
  }
}
new Varien.Tabs('.tabs');
</script>
```

Comment: CaN this code be used in the homepage ? I would like to create tabs on homepage and category page and populate with 'New Products' 'Popular Products' 'Most Viewed Products' etc?